# Image after text

Tags: html, css

I want an image that has the witdh 75 and height 100 after this text:

```
<b>Het boek</b><br>
<p>Boek nummer: 1 <br>
Aantal punten: 6 <br>
Aantal bladzijden: 400 </p>
```

Can someone help me? I know i probably have to put an div around it, but i dont know the css.
By the way, the image will be on the page using the img tags

Comment: Why won't <p><img src="image.png" /></p> work?

Comment: Can you show us an image of how you want it to look, and explain why @frustratedtech's answer doesn't fulfil your needs? And an up-vote? For *this*? Good grief... =/

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<div style="float:left;">
your text or any other thing
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<img src="somewhere"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple page, is this what you're looking for?

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <b>Het boek</b><br>
  <p>Boek nummer: 1 <br>
  Aantal punten: 6 <br>
  Aantal bladzijden: 400 </p>
  <img alt="Show this text when the mouse is over the image." height="75" width="100" src="test.jpg">
  </body>
  </html>
```

"Show this text when the mouse is over the image." can be changed to some text you desire or the alt attribute can be removed altogether. The height and width attributes will force the dimensions you desire. The src attribute needs to be pointed at the location of the image. The image can be any HTML support image type, it does not need to be a jpg. It can be jpg, png, gif, etc.

More information on the  tag and other HTML resources can be found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="URL_IMAGE" style="margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px; float: left; " />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/emRNK/

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/75x100">
<div>
    <h1>Het boek</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Boek nummer: 1</li>
        <li>Aantal punten: 6</li>
        <li>Aantal bladzijden: 400</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a good article on float: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/float

Here's why I included `overflow: hidden` on the `<div>` element (note that if you remove it, the padding will not work): http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 8 years old, but if you're needing help as I was, this is how you do it on HTML5:

```
<p><img src="source" alt="Example" style="float:right;width: 75px;height:100px;">Just put your paragraph here</p>
```

very easy :)

here, just look for "Image Floating" for some better explanation 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

just use the: <img src="insertImageAdressHere" alt="TheImage" and then close it.

Comment: kindly format the code accordingly with three ticks 
```
the code here
```